# Displaying a Cell's Value into a Constant text

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

So i'm trying to make an IF statement and if its true I would like it to display a sentence with the cells value. Can someone tell me where i'm going wrong here?

```
Sheets("Quote Sheet").Cells(Row3, 2) = "     •     " & Sheets("CostSheet").Cells(46, 4).Value & "- Broan Model #QTXE90 Low Some Exhaust fan for"
```

Comment: I don't see any issues here. What's the problem?

Comment: `Sheets("Quote Sheet").Cells(Row3, 2)` needs to be `Sheets("Quote Sheet").Cells(3, 2)`

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk not if `Row3` is a variable. A poorly named one, but a variable just the saem.

Comment: And if it isn't a variable then that line would error and OP has not share an error with is, so I'm led to believe that the issue is either with it's value or OP hasn't shared that valuable piece of info. You wouldn't withhold an error message from us though, would you @xVias?

Comment: An If statement is to compare/evaluate and provide an output whether it is true or false. So what are you comparing/evaluating?

Comment: So my problem was I didn't put a space in between "Quote Sheet" haha. Thanks for your reply's!

Comment: That would have thrown an error. Please next time share the error. That's a very valuable piece of information for troubleshooting.

Comment: Basically I am using an If Statement to test if a cells value is greater  then 0 and if it is then I want it to display a sentence onto another sheet. I only had problems with the one line (which I see my really dumb error now) so I didn't add the whole If statement @Ricardo A

Comment: Ill make sure to do that next time haha @JNevill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a context in which the code functions:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim Row3 As Long
    Row3 = 3
    Sheets("Quote Sheet").Cells(Row3, 2) = "     •     " & Sheets("CostSheet").Cells(46, 4).Value & "- Broan Model #QTXE90 Low Some Exhaust fan for"
End Sub
```